# Error with async await keywords

Tags: c#, async-ctp, async-await

i added the AsyncCtpLibrary v.3. grabbed some sample code from the async webpage.  wrapped it in a TestFixture to play around with.

i'm getting errors:  any ideas why?

Error 1 - Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Error 2 - ; expected

code:

```
 [TestFixture]
public class AsyncTests
{
    [Test]
    public async void AsyncRunCpu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("On the UI thread.");

        int result = await TaskEx.Run(
            () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting CPU-intensive work on background thread...");
                    int work = DoCpuIntensiveWork();
                    Console.WriteLine("Done with CPU-intensive work!");
                    return work;
                });

        Console.WriteLine("Back on the UI thread.  Result is {0}.", result);
    }

    public int DoCpuIntensiveWork()
    {
        // Simulate some CPU-bound work on the background thread:
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean you're using VS11 for the async/await keywords. Not sure if it'll make much difference but try new Task.Factory.StartNew. Also try adding .Result after the Run command. The .Result is the Tasks return type, in this case a int

Comment: Check if you have an Async CTP folder under `My Documents`. There have been many installation issues with the async CTP [discussed on the forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads). It boils down to the fact that the async CTP is an out-of-band update that interferes with other VS updates. At this point (with VS11 imminent) I think it is unlikely they will fix the installer. Once VS11 is released, I expect the Async CTP will be pulled and no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task AsyncRunCpu()
{
    // ...
}
```

as far as I can tell async methods with a `void` return type are in some way special - wonder why the compiler doesn't issue a warning for this kind of scenario ...

By the way you can use `async/await` with .NET4.0, just add a reference to [Microsoft.BCL.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) in the project. The only difference is that some `Task` related functionality lives in the `TaskEx` type.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply add the .dll to your project and have it work: the Async CTP extends the syntax of the C# language, the "normal" compiler doesn't understand the new keywords, even if the required runtime assembly is present. You need to install it using the official installer. (Note: uninstall all Visual Studio updates since the last service pack first, or the install won't succeed. You can reinstall the updates afterwards.)

Comment: Why use the async CTP when VS11 beta is now available, and presumably won't affect a VS10 installation?

Comment: @JonSkeet Without the Async CTP, .NET 4.5 is required at runtime, right? That's not necessarily a bad thing, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: I wouldn't personally use the Async CTP for production at the moment - there are too many gotchas. I would definitely just work with the beta instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looking at your blog, http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/10/eduasync-part-10-ctp-bug-don-t-combine-multiple-awaits-in-one-statement.aspx is a good reason to avoid the CTP if using VS11 is an option at all -- though again, the CTP is better than nothing when VS11 is not an option.

Comment: i'm using VS10.  i saw this link http://codesnack.com/blog/2012/02/16/visual-studio-async-ctp-version-3-installation-issues.  i had one of the 3 hotfixes installed and removed it but that didn't resolve my problem.  then i tried VS11 beta but that's giving me a installation error :(

Comment: @CurlyFro I don't know enough about VS11 to say anything useful about that, but as for the CTP, I have been able to install it without issues on different systems, that were fully up-to-date before installation, by first uninstalling the *six* hotfixes: 2522890, 2529927, 2548139, 2549864, 2565057, 2635973. (Perhaps only some need removing.) If you found only one, I wonder if you have others that cause problems that you might have overlooked. I'm also not sure where you've looked: they're available from Programs and Features > View installed updates, not from Programs and Features directly.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks, you helped me figure out a puzzling problem. I wish I had know this early, I would of had saved a lot of time.